# Erro ao comparar datas ORA-00932

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Estou com um problema para realizar a comparação entre 2 datas no oracle. Estou utilizando o método case para comparar as datas e ao final isso deveria retornar para minha tabela um número, que no caso representa uma idade, porém, recebo p erro informando:

PL/SQL: ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava DATE obteve NUMBER.

Segue abaixo o trecho de código que dá o erro.

```
(case when T1.ANO_MODELO = 0 then 0 else (case when ((W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO) - T1.ANO_MODELO) < 0 then 0 else ((W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO) - T1.ANO_MODELO) End) End)
```

Comment: Veja o link a seguir no stackoverflow em inglês. Acredito ele responda sua pergunta. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759515/asking-user-to-input-date-in-sql-giving-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expec

Answer (score 2):

Todos os resultados do seu *case* devem retornar o mesmo tipo de dado. O erro ocorre porque numa situação retorna um *number* e em outra situação retorna um *date*.

O **W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO** é um *date*? O **T1.ANO_MODELO** é um *number*?

---

**[EDIT]**

Onde você faz:

```
((W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO) - T1.ANO_MODELO)
```

Substitua por:

```
trunc(
(
W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO - to_date(extract(day from W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO) || '/' || extract(month from W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO) || '/' || T1.ANO_MODELO, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
) / 365 )
```

Essa "fórmula" acima te retornará um valor inteiro que representa o número de anos do veículo. Faça um teste e veja se resolve.

Comment: Electus, pois é ... O grande lance é que nesse case, preciso comparar a idade de um veículo e faço isso da seguinte forma:

W_REG.DAT_ENVIO_CALCULO = formato data normal, ex: 21/07/2014
T1.ANO_MODELO = formato número, ex: 2011
Desta forma, preciso usar a subtração para obter a idade de um veículo, por exemplo 5 anos.

Comment: Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ok. Já que funcionou, peço a gentileza de marcar a resposta como correta. Obrigado.